# When deploying with AWS and executing, I encountered the error message "Missing Authentication Token."

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a Lambda function and uploaded it as `.zip` on AWS and also created an API gateway for it. Then I run the url `https://xqdbaikl85.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/data/api/v1/series/` on browser and got the error like `"message": "Missing Authentication Token"`.

this is my Folder Structure

```
API
├── ApiRoutes
│   ├── series.js
│   ├── articles.js
│   ├── auth.js
│   ├── columns.js
│   ├── labels.js
│   └── users.js
├── models
│   ├── Series.js
│   ├── Article.js
│   ├── Column.js
│   ├── Label.js
│   └── User.js
├── node_modules
├── RoutesController
│   ├── series.js
│   ├── articles.js
│   ├── auth.js
│   ├── columns.js
│   ├── labels.js
│   └── users.js
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── errorMessage.js
├── index.js
├── JWT_TOKEN.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

These are part of my code.

API/**ApiRoutes/series.js**

```
import express from "express";
import { createSeries, deleteSeries, getAllSeries, updatedSeries } from "../RoutesController/series.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAllSeries)
router.post("/", createSeries)
router.put("/:id", updatedSeries)
router.delete("/:id", deleteSeries)

export default router
```

API/**models/Series.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const seriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
})

export default mongoose.model("Series", seriesSchema)
```

API/**RoutesController/series.js**

```
import { errorMessage } from '../errorMessage.js';
import Series from '../models/Series.js';

export const createSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
    const series = new Series(req.body)
    try {
        const saveSeries = await series.save();
        res.status(200).json(saveSeries)
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 11000) {
            return res.status(500).json("系列名稱重複")
        } else errorMessage(500, "系列建立失敗", error)
    }
}
export const getAllSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const series = await Series.find();
        res.status(200).json(series);
    } catch (error) {
        next(errorMessage(500, "系列搜尋失敗，為資料庫變動問題", error))
    }
}

export const updatedSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const updateSeries = await Series.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { new: true });
        res.status(200).json(updateSeries);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 11000) {
            return res.status(500).json("系列名稱重複")
        } else next(errorMessage(500, "系列的更新失敗，可能為格式錯誤或是找不到其ID", error))
    }
}

export const deleteSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await Series.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json("系列成功刪除")
    } catch (error) {
        next(errorMessage(500, "刪除系列失敗", error))
    }
}
```

API/**index.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import articlesApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/articles.js";
import usersApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/users.js";
import authApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/auth.js";
import labelsApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/labels.js";
import columnsApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/columns.js";
import seriesApiRouter from "./ApiRoutes/series.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"

dotenv.config();

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB)
        console.log("connected to MongoDB");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("disconnect to MongoDB");
    }
}

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
});
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("MongoDB disconnect");
});

const app = express();
// const port = 5000;
// app.listen(port, () => {
//     connect();
//     console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
// })

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/v1/articles", articlesApiRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/users", usersApiRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authApiRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/labels", labelsApiRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/columns", columnsApiRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/series", seriesApiRouter);

app.use((error,req,res,next) => {
    const errorStatus = error.status || 500;
    const errorMessage = error.message || "Something went wrong";
    return res.status(errorStatus).json({
        status: errorStatus,
        message: errorMessage
    })
})
export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    connect();
    const response = app
    return response;
};
```

aws lambda setting: [aws lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxNEr.png)
CloudWatch Logs: [CloudWatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCd1O.png)

I'm not sure what could be causing the error, so I've included a portion of the code and photos.  Please advise me on how to resolve it? Thank you very much!

I run it on localhost is like
[run on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zte9r.png)